# What's best way to show the same results to a user based on their postcode?

Tags: php, algorithm, search, random

I'm developing a website where a user can search for 'something' near their **location that they enter** (in the UK). There maybe say up to 10+ matching results, but the client only wants 3 results to be shown at any one time. Because each 'something' is paying the same amount to be listed, each 'something' should have the same chance of being displayed...and these results should not change each time the same user makes the search..

I'm thinking use the users postcode as a seed, and randomly select 3 results out of the matching list. Would this be a good way of achieving this? what are my other options?

Comment: I'd probably use something more unique to the user than postcode, especially if you have any international plans. US zip codes are huge.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the last two octets of the IP address that initiated the request as a random seed.  That would give you a somewhat evenly-distributed 65,536 possible seed values.  I would then set their IP address back to them in a cookie in case they are connecting through a network that randomizes the external address they connect from.  You'd use the value of the cookie if it's present, otherwise use their actual address.

I say the last two octets instead of the first two since using the first two will cause e.g. all users of the same local ISP to wind up receiving the same results, and I'd expect the last two octets to be much more evenly distributed by your users.

Note that for e.g. companies or universities that route all traffic through one address, all of the users in that institution would see the same results with this approach.

If you are not adverse to the idea of cookies, set a 1-year or so cookie that renews with each visit, containing 64 bits or so of random garbage.  Then use that as your seed.

Comment: You can always add more data to a seed: if your PRNG only takes 16 bits of seed data, you could use the last 16 bits of a hash of the full IP address.

Comment: Thats a good idea thanks, although if the user happens to repeat the search at another location, but for their house address they will not have the same result. Also if going through one IP address, it may give a unfair advantage to one particular listing

Comment: @davivid: How would that be any different than if they were to travel to a different zip code and search from there?

Comment: and to strengthen your point, "travelling to a different zip code" is even easier in the UK than the US. Our post codes typically cover about 10 street addresses. Used to be I could travel to another post code by accidentally connecting to the wrong wireless network, although everyone encrypts these days...

Comment: no problem because the form is essentially 'enter your address', doesn't matter where you are... you could even be in another country as long as the result stays the same for the postcode you enter

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to be random which items they get shown, why not just use PHP's [rand function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php) to generate a random seed? Once their seed has been generated, you can save a cookie with the value. When loading the page, check to see if the cookie exists. If it does, use the value in the cookie; if it doesn't, then regenerate the random number and create a new cookie. It wouldn't work if the user clears their cookies every time they close the browser, but most people don't do that.